# Error on re-import: #1231 - Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Using phpMyAdmin, I was getting an error when importing a MySQL dump file to which I'd made a simple global find-and-replace:

```
Error
SQL query:

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
MySQL said:

#1231 - Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
```

The strange thing is I had just exported the dump, and this is all I did.

So then I tried exporting a .zip again, and re-importing **without making any changes**. And I got the same error.

I was able to import the file, finally, by deleting these lines from the dump:

```
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

But I'd like the export/import process to just work.

So my question is: **How can I prevent this from happening with future imports, in a way that doesn't require looking up this issue again?**

Note: I'm on a shared server setup; I don't currently have SSH access.

Answer (score 0):

Not a user of *phpMyAdmin*, but *mysqldump* has an option to disable those lines from the dump:

- [`--skip-set-charset`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_set-charset)

Unfortunately, this will work if you have access to *mysqldump*. Not sure if *phpMyAdmin* has configurable options for export, but hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I only have access to phpmyadmin. The export function only shows one setting related to charset — setting the charset of the file itself. Which I've set to utf-8 (it's a dropdown setting)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if my.cnf or some other setting, perhaps via phpmyadmin, has set some of those variables to NULL before executing that script.  Rummage around; if you find it, change it.

Alternatively, you can edit the dump file to remove the offending lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch closely this (meta) commmand is executed at the far end of the import. As the import was performed correctly you can savely ignore this error.